# jQuery smooth scroll and link to another page

Tags: jquery, laravel, anchor, smooth-scrolling

This is my menu structure:

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#highlights">Highlights</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="highlights">
  //some content inside for the highlights
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $('a[href="#highlights"]').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#highlights").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
```

This way I can achieve smooth scrolling to the specific part of the page (in this case Highlights).

It works fine, but when I enter let's say the contact page:

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact
```

and when I click on highlights it doesn't go back to the homepage, but it simply adds the parameter to the URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact#highlights
```

Of course, because the highlights is on the homepage. 
If I do the link for highlights like this:

```
<a href="/#highlights">Highlights</a>
```

it will go to the homepage and the specific part Highlights, but if I click now again on the Highlights menu link, it breaks the smooth scrolling.

Is there any solution for that?

I've tried changing my jQuery code like this:

```
  $('a[href="/#highlights"]').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("/#highlights").offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
```

but it didn't worked too.

EDIT. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

EDIT2: Gezzasa has posted brilliant idea and I've tweaked a little bit.

To work properly, the homepage should have a additional class, so the next jQuery code to work like it should.
Let's say I'm adding class "front" on my home page and use the Gezzasa idea, this is working properly:

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/#highlights" data-anchor="#highlights">Highlights</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="highlights">
  //some content inside for the highlights
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $('.front [data-anchor]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var goToAnchor = $(this).attr("data-anchor");
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(goToAnchor).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: what happens if you change `/#highlights` to `/index.html#highlights`

Comment: `scrollTop: $("/#highlights").offset().top
    }, 1000);` won't work because `/#highlights` is an invalid selector for jquery.

Comment: My website is Laravel, so if I change to /index.php#highlights it goes to the specific part of the page, but without any smooth scrolling.

Comment: /index.php#highlights and /#highlights acts the same.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing a couple of things.

I added a data parameter on the a tag called `data-anchor`. You can call it whatever you like.

I then placed the id in there so that I can completely ignore the href and prevent the default behavior of the `a` tag
`<a href="#" data-anchor="#highlights">SmoothScroll</a>`

I then used a listener to add the click event to the element once the dom has been loaded.

https://jsfiddle.net/qf0duLb1/17/

Now it will scroll smoothly IF that anchor is on the page.

I hope I've actually answered your question or I might have understood it wrong. There probably is much better solutions out there. This worked for me.

Comment: That is a great idea, but it's not complete, because when I',m on different page it wont take me back. I found the solution, I will edit my main thread, you can edit your answer and I'll accept it. Please check the post again in 3 minutes.

Comment: OK, now you can edit your answer. Thank you very much!